# Crash caused by animation cancel()

Tags: java, android, animation, listener, cancellation

I have 2 animations, slide[1] and slide[3], and when I try to cancel them when the animation repeats itself, it causes a crash. here is some relevant code:

```
        slide[1].setDuration(500); slide[1].setStartDelay(500);
    slide[3].setDuration(500); slide[3].setStartDelay(500);
    slide[1].addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
            if (!start) {
                table[2][2].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.black);
                slide[1].setDuration(1000);
                slide[1].setStartDelay(0);
                slide[3].setDuration(1000);
                slide[3].setStartDelay(0);
                slide[1].removeAllListeners();
                slide[3].cancel();
                slide[1].cancel();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        }

    }); slide[1].start(); slide[3].start();
```

The line which causes the crash is "slide[1].cancel();", and I don't know why.
Apparently the crash is being caused when the phone is running on JellyBean, but not Marshmallow for example.
How can I solve this problem?

Thanks!

UPDATE: here is the logcat:

```
03-13 16:18:01.943 1623-1623/com.example.ohad.squerz E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
                                                                       at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
                                                                       at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
                                                                       at android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler.doAnimationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:603)
                                                                       at android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler.run(ValueAnimator.java:639)
                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:524)
                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: print you logcat here

Comment: Added the logcat. Notice that the problem is caused in JellyBean but not in Marshmallow. Thanks!

Comment: Hello, i know this is an (very) old issue, but i'm experiencing the same crash in jellybean as well. Do you remember what was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This crash has been fixed in AOSP in [this commit](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/commit/2936fc0244ab2010696b3b1d723d6bbbc693916e#diff-18403564b1f45b37bdd807e1eda5b0d8).

If you want to support API 16, you need to cancel your animations somewhere else than in `onAnimationUpdate`/`onAnimationRepeat`.

In your case (if it matters, because this answer comes a long time after your question), you probably want to avoid the repeat on your first animator, using `setRepeatCount(0)`.